# Replace zeros in decimal part with blanks

Tags: java, regex

If a string is a = 500.000 I need to convert it to a = 500 Any help in java using regex ?

i tried replaceAll("\G0", "") but it worked for leading zeros . Also i need the zeros to stay if there is an other number after them. like if a = 500.0001, i need it to stay a = 500.0001.

Comment: Better to use a = parseInt('500.000',10)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you appear to want all trailing zeros to be removed, but only if they are part of the fraction part of the number.

```java
replaceAll("\\.0+$", "")
```

will work. Breakdown of regex:

- `\\.` matches a literal dot.
- `0+` matches one or more zeros.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

---

Note: you have not given enough context of why you want to do this. But if you need decimal numbers, then you could also parse using `Double.parseDouble(yourString)` or `new BigDecimal(yourString)`.

Answer (score 0):

To replace trailing zeros, you can use
replaceAll("\.0{0,}$", "")

\.  The pattern starts with a dot (.). Since dot has a special meaning in regex, it needs to be escaped and since the regex pattern is a java string, the escape character needs to be escaped too, hence we have double escape characters.
0{0,}  After a dot, there can be zero or more 0's.
$  finds a match at the end of a string

With this pattern, even if you have 500. (with a dot at the end without any trailing 0's), it will remove the dot and return 500